# How to properly write a custom Layer when NextDecoder depends on the previous layer, not the current one?

Tags: go, gopacket

I am writing custom layer decoders with *gopacket*.

**LayerA** contains a field `Type` that can be one of the following values:

- *B-only*, the next layer is **LayerB**, followed by a raw payload
- *C-only*, the next layer is **LayerC**, followed by a raw payload
- *B-C*, the next layer is **LayerB**, followed by **LayerC** then a raw payload

There is no field in **LayerB** that can be used to know if **LayerC** is the next or not. **LayerB** and **LayerC** decoding does not depend on whenever the other layer is present or not.

What would be the proper way to write the decode function of **LayerA**, since it's the one that knows what are the next layers?

There is not a lot of tutorials about custom layers with *gopacket*, and this case is not like the basic ones covered there.

It seems the logic should be put in **LayerA** decoding function, just before calling `p.NextDecoder`.

I thought of two ways to achieve this:

## 1. Use a closure

Add a field `nextDecoder Decoder` to the struct **LayerB**.
In the decoder of **LayerA**, when `Type` is *C-only*, simply use the decoder of **LayerC**. Otherwise, create a struct **LayerB** and  fill the field `nextDecoder` accordingly. Then use this struct in a closure, that will be used as the next decoder.

### Issues

The decoding logic of **LayerB** would be in the **LayerA** decoding function (see code in Palyground below).
Moreover, which decoding function to use when registering the **LayerB** with `gopacket.RegisterLayer`?

## 2. Have two separate layers LayerB-C and LayerB-only

**LayerB-C** next decoder would be `LayerC`'s, **LayerB-only**'s would be just the payload layer.

### Issues

The decoding function of **LayerB-only** and **LayerB-C** is the same, expect the call the `p.NextDecoder`.
Since there is no notion of 'inheritance' in go, I am not sure how to design this to avoid duplication. Maybe create a **LayerB-base** interface with a function `nextDecoder() LayerType`, and make **LayerB-C** and **LayerB-only** implement it? Or embed a type **LayerB-base** that has a function `Decode`? But neither of them doesn't feel right.

## Code

Here is some code for each described way: https://play.golang.org/p/N9ZpYqFb16Q. The actual content of the layers are not relevant, except `LayerA.Type`.

The result of this code is as expected but I would like to know if there is a better or more idiomatic to do it.

Comment: It sounds a lot like you're describing a system where the payload belongs to `LayerA`, with `LayerB` and `LayerC` being optional headers for that layer rather than new levels of encapsulation.  That might just be due to the simplified version of the problem you've presented here though.

Comment: Hi @JamesHenstridge, ah yes it makes sense to see them as optional headers! I think it's the case, since it's `LayerA` only that knows about their presence. Thank you, it will simplify the structure!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by declaring the next layer to be an interface, which could support either B or C.  As long as whatever you declare fits as a LayerType, this should work fine.